# Migrating from ExtJS grids to ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, grid, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to migrate a project from ExtJS to Angular. In ExtJS a number of metadata are sent to server (e.g. total,page,limit,filters, and so on). However, ng grid does not sent any metadata to server. Also, it seems that the response should only contains an array of result. How client know the totals number rows on the server? And Generally, how can I streamline ExtJS to Angular migration process?

Also, what is the counterpart of column's `renderer` in ui-grid (I mean a function not a tempalte)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with extJS.  Having said that, I'm reasonably familiar with ui-grid.  The reason that the total, page, limit etc aren't sent to the server is that you retrieve the data yourself from outside the grid.  You should apply any filters to the http request before you give the data to the grid.

If you're using pagination, then take a look at the external pagination tutorial (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/318_external_pagination), that sounds closest to what you're expecting, and it allows you to specify pages etc.  Personally if I was going to page from the server I'd use infinite scroll instead (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll).

In my application I use neither - I use the custom filter editor (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/308_external_filtering) to record filters that I want to apply to the server, and apply those filters to the http request before I send it.  I don't deal with pagination because I generally have less than 500 rows, and both my server and client are OK to pass around that amount of data.  If I was going much beyond that I'd look probably at infinite scroll, but that's quite a bit more work.